# Does wp_new_comment expect a comment in HTML?

Tags: comments

Should the `comment_content` in this example contain HTML? Or should it contain plain text?

```
$comment_id = wp_new_comment([
    'comment_post_ID' => 1,
    'comment_content' => 'Tom & Jerry', // or should this be 'Tom &amp; Jerry'?
    'comment_type' => '',
    'user_id' => 1,
    // etc
]);
```

For completeness, does the same apply to `wp_insert_comment` too?

Comment: Can't you simply try this out? Should or should not probably depends on what exactly it is you want to achieve - which we don't know as it stands

Comment: Based on my reading of the source code, it just inserts the content as is into the database, and now I need to check to see if the database expects HTML, it's not obvious. I was hoping to simply find the answer in the documentation or in Google. I want to get it right to prevent improper escaping.

Answer (score 1):

> or should this be 'Tom & Jerry'?

It doesn't really matter. It's more important to consider if you don't know where the comment content is coming from. If you're inserting user input as the comment content then this should be escaped.

`wp_new_comment()` escapes and sanititizes the comment for you. It's designed to take the user input from the comment form directly and sanitise it before passing it to `wp_insert_comment()`.

So this includes encoding HTML entitites (converting `&` to `&amp;`) and filtering out disallowed HTML. It also does things like add the commenter's IP address to the comment.

So when using `wp_new_comment()` you shouldn't need to do any escaping and should enter the comment the same way the user would, with one important exception.

Both `wp_new_comment()` and `wp_insert_comment()` expect data to be *slashed*. WordPress automatically runs [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on everything in `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` and these functions are expecting the data to be slashed because they are made to use data from those variables.

So if any of the data for the comment you're inserting includes quotes or slashes then you need to slash it with `wp_slash()` before inserting:

```
$args = [
    'comment_post_ID' => 1,
    'comment_content' => 'Tom\'s a cat',
    'comment_type' => '',
    'user_id' => 1,
];

$comment_id = wp_new_comment( wp_slash( $args ) );
```

Note that the slash I already added, `Tom\'s` was escaping it for PHP purposes, and still needs to be slashed.

The silly thing is that the first thing that happens in `wp_insert_comment()` is that it runs `wp_unslash()`. So we're adding slashes just for them to be removed immediately. But it needs to be done for consistency with the `$_POST` variable and so that slashes that might be part of the content aren't incorrectly removed.

Comment: I don't think `wp_new_comment` escapes the input, `Tom & Jerry` gets turned into `Tom &amp; Jerry`, but `Tom &amp; Jerry` remains as `Tom &amp; Jerry` instead of `Tom &amp;amp; Jerry`.

Comment: I think knowing the rules of when to escape and when not to escape is important. As if to prove this point, the first paragraph in your answer I think was interpreted as HTML when you did not expect it to.

Comment: It does escape the input. `wp_new_comment()` calls `wp_filter_comment()` on all the data. This applies the `pre_comment_content` filters to the comment content. By default `wp_filter_kses` or `wp_filter_post_kses` (depending on the user role) is applied to `pre_comment_content`. One of the things `wp_kses` does is run `wp_kses_normalize_entities()`, which runs functions like `wp_kses_named_entities()`, `wp_kses_normalize_entities2()` and `wp_kses_normalize_entities3()`. This whole process ensures entities are not double-escaped.